# Firebase observing object at it's key-path returns it's children one by one

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm using the Firebase IOS SDK and I've setup security to have each message be readable/writeable only by it's owner. To listen for message-changes I need to observe each message at it's message-key path with `observeEventType:(FEventTypeChildChanged/FEventTypeChildAdded)`. 
The problem I'm facing here is that each time a message is updated/added remotely, Firebase will return for each of the children of the message (properties name and message) a separate snapshot. The snapshot-dictionary will only contain one child at the time with it's corresponding value. Is there a way to have the full message returned with all it's children instead having them returned one by one ?

```
-messages
  --message_key_a
     --name
     --message
  --message_key_b
     --name
     --message
  --message_key_c
     --name
     --message

 --users
    --user_key_a
      --name
      --messages
          --message_key_a
          --message_key_c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for the `value` event with:

```
ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
```

But if each message is only readable by its owner, it sounds like you have the wrong data model. Why don't you store the messages for each owner under a node for that owner:

```
/messages_per_user
    $uid
        $messageid
            name
            message
```

That way you can give read/write access on `/messages_per_user/$uid`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages_per_user": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't get your remark about the data model, but I thought I did actually store all the messages for each owner. As you can see in my question post there are right there under users/user_key_a/messages. This node contains all references to messages which belong to 'user_key_a'. Please correct if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Those are just the message ids, not the messages themselves. If you only/mostly need to access the messages for a specific user: store them under that user only (and not in a global `/messages` anymore). If you need the global list, use `FEventTypeValue` on the specific message id.

Comment: I went with only storing message ids to keep the option open where a user possible could share a message with another user. Where in case I'd store the message directly under the owner's node, that message would only be accessible to that user only indefinitely.